# How to load information in AngularJs Constructor

Tags: angularjs

**Scenario:**
When user requests the page, some information is fetched from Database and needs to be populated in AngularJs Model (properties) on Page Load.

My AngularJS reside in a separate JS file and the fetched information(in JSON format) can only be rendered in view.

How can I load the fetched JSON information in AngualarJs properties. The values needs to be updated as soon as page is rendered, so I was considering Constructor; but don't know any way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a method, say '$scope.loadConstructor()' and called it in my AngularJs code.